# Can I run R on an alternate hard drive in Windows?

Tags: r

I installed R in `C:/programfiles/users...` directory. All my files are on a different hard drive, at `N:/project/rasterimg/stacked/...`. The size of files I want to use for my work are very large (126 GB), so I can not move them to C: drive.

Is there any method to run R without moving my files into C drive?

Answer (score 1):

run

```
setwd("directory_path")
```

as already suggested. Then check with

```
getwd()
```

if you are really, where you wanted to be.
Then run

```
dir()
```

to see/list what files are there in your working dorectory. 
You can even acces the file via its the dir() function output index number if you want to avoid mis-typing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to change your working directory to some kind of external hard drive. You can do that by using the command:

```
setwd("N:/project/rasterimg/stacked/...")
```

or you can just access your files by reading them through a command like (or similarly for the objects you work with):

```
read.table("N:/project/rasterimg/stacked/...")
```

Edit: My concern with working with 126 GB files would be that you will run out of memory though... but that's a totally different issue, which is somewhat beyond my knowledge. But there might be others that could help you with that in a new thread (if needed).

Comment: I have changed working the directory as you suggested. After that I wanted to read an image file as following:                            ndvi2000<-readBin("2000_all11_con_filtr.envi"). Still an error appeared here, meaning that No such file or directory.

Comment: have you tried
ndvi2000<-readBin(con=file("2000_all11_con_filtr.envi", "rb"))